# How to not include large files in git

Tags: git, web

So basically, I use git and Github for a website. A specific directory on this website contains really large files that do not get changed. However, other files do get changed. I just change them and push my changes. How do I make it where my large files stay on the remote repository but not on my local machine? If I use something like iPower, it works the way I intend, but I will have to replace each file individually every time I change it. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at git LFS. https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: @AlbertoCasas thanks! it still git lfs still keeps the files on my computer though. i just want to have a remote database that i never touch, but i want to be able to access it through my website, like "<domain>.com/large-files"